# How do you apply a macro x amount of times per line where x depends on the line

Tags: vim, vim-macros

Say I have something like

```
a & 1234567890
b & 1234567890
c & 1234567890
d & 1234567890
e & 1234567890
f & 1234567890
```

Is there a way to use a vim macro such that I can run a macro/command x amount of times per line, where x depends on the line?
In this case, I run `2wx^` on each line x times, where x is the line number such that the result becomes

```
a & 234567890
b & 34567890
c & 4567890
d & 567890
e & 67890
f & 7890
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your macro is recorded in register `q`, then you can run:

```
:exec 'normal ' . line('.') . '@q'
```

on any line you want. Your macro will want the cursor kept on 1st column before being run.

You can also probably do it - better - in a different way, if you describe *what* you want to do. For example, perhaps you could skip the macro altogether and use something like this instead:

```
:exec 'normal ^2w' . line('.') . 'xj'
```

If you need a line offset (e.g. of `1`), you could use:

```
:let nr = line('.') - 1 | execute 'normal ^2w' . nr . 'xj'
```